Shared Libraries in jenkins not working in parameters
I am trying to optimize my Jenkins scripts with the usage of shared libraries. I created a repository, created a vars directory and added two groovy scripts:
.
`-- vars
    |-- buildDockerImage.groovy
    `-- getSvnOptions.groovy

This is the configuration of my shared library:

When i try to use them in a pipeline it works as expected and returns the expected output e.g.
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build and Test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // Use the shared library function
                    def choices = getSvnOptions('https://svn.test.com/svn/projects/scripts', 'trunk', true, true)
                    echo "${choices}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Although, when i try to add an active choice parameter to be populated from this function it does not work:


The return of the script is in ['A', 'B', ...] format. Additionally, i tried to execute it from jenkins/script page but i get the following error:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.getSvnOptions() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean) values: [https://svn.test.com/svn/projects/scripts, trunk, true, true]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:80)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:193)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:574)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:612)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:583)

Same applied for my other method which does not have any arguments so the arguments are not the issue. Do you have any idea on how i can use this function to populate the active choice parameter?

The only way you can reuse an Active Choices script is by using scriptler. Global shared libraries are not loaded in the script ran by this parameter definition. You can find examples of this configuration in the Active Choices plugin documentation.

you can try do something like this in the pipeline script itself:
properties([
   parameters([
        choice(choices:getSvnOptions('https://svn.test.com/svn/projects/scripts', 'trunk', true, true),
    name: 'svn choices')
                ])
         ])

